# ng2 [disabled]="!myInput.value" doesnt work correctly

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm building a standard angular2 app(more specific a todo app). I also added [@Ngrx/store](https://github.com/ngrx/store).

The first time I load the page, the button is disabled, but when I enter some value in the input box, the button needs to be enabled, but it stays disabled...

`app/app.component.ts`

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
  <div>
    <add-todo></add-todo>
  </div>`,
})
export class AppComponent  { name = 'Angular'; }
```

`app/components/add-todo/add-todo.component.ts`

```js
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'add-todo',
  template: `
    Create new todo
    <input #myInput />
    <button (click)="addTodo()" [disabled]="!myInput.value">Add</button>`
})
export class AddTodoComponent {
  @ViewChild('myInput') input: ElementRef;

  constructor() {}

  addTodo(): void {
    alert(this.input.nativeElement.value);
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to take care about change detection. It might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41608443/angular2-what-does-binding-event-to-0-mean

Comment: Hmm...I think what you're trying to do, is if the nativElement has a value (per the plain old html "value" attribute), you want the enabled/disabled toggled? I'm not sure that would work, I don't know if a nativeElement attribute as-is is something that Angular would "see". What I think would serve you better, is either bind the value of <input [(ngModel)]="myVal">, or bind to an event of input (like change or something), and set the value that determines true/false there (like in the onChange handler, "if ( val ) disabled = false" or some such like that).

Comment: Adding ngModel didn't work for me, but just adding (keyup)="0" like [yurzui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5485167/yurzui) mentioned solved it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html Track the change state and validity of form controls using ngModel...

Update your code to use ngModel and it should work as expected

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'add-todo',
  template: `
    Create new todo
    <input #myInput [(ngModel)]="inputFieldValue" />
    <button (click)="addTodo()" [disabled]="!myInput.value">Add</button>`
})
export class AddTodoComponent {

  @ViewChild('myInput') input: ElementRef;
  public inputFieldValue:string = '';

  constructor() {}

  addTodo(): void {
    alert(this.input.nativeElement.value);
  }
}
```

Comment: I copy/pasted your snippet, but I get the following error:
zone.js:420 Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot set property 'stack' of undefined ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot set property 'stack' of undefined
    at SyntaxError.set [as stack] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:1628:63)...

Comment: Have you imported the forms module to your project?

Comment: I was using zone version 0.7.5, I reverted this to 0.7.4 and fixed this problem, now it's working [github-zone-issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3975#issuecomment-272364925)

Answer (score 0):

What if you do this way:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'add-todo',
  template: `
    Create new todo
    <input #todoTitleInput [(ngModel)]="todoTitle"/>
    <button (click)="addTodo(todoTitleInput.value)" [disabled]="!todoTitle">Add</button>
  `,
})
export class AddTodoComponent {
  addTodo(title: string): void {
    alert(title);
  }
}
```